# Open a new window/tab using h:commandButton or p:commandButton?

Tags: java, primefaces

The requirement is to open a new window/tab on button click. The new window should redirect to new URL or say new page. I have tried the below code:

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'"/>
```

but this opens the current page again. How shall I set new page or url to open in new window/tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{backing.popupDlg(row.id)}" immediate="true" value="Dialog">
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="@form" listener="#{backing.refreshPage}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

BACKING:

```
public void popupDlg(Integer id) {
    //USER CODE
    // DO something with ID

    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("closable", false);
    options.put("draggable", true);
    options.put("resizable", true);
    options.put("contentHeight", 620);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("DlgPage", options, null);
}
```

This also handle dialog return updation/deletion/insertion for master page while it opens `DlgPage.xhtml` in dialog

Comment: Do you mean we will call editDesignationDlg(Integer dsgnId) of backing bean by actionListener="#{backing.popupDlg(row.id)}". popupDlg(row.id) is just a typo rather it should be editDesignationDlg or its different.

Comment: Editing issue, For me, I used this in p:datatable so i passed row id to backing method. If you have standard pop-up for all you would not required any id. You can use the basic idea from it. As it is pretty clear

Comment: My requirement is to open a new tab/window on button submit rather than a dialog/pop-up on the same page. I could n't get that logic from what you have shared.